# Outlook APIs for getting meeting room details whether room is booked or not

Tags: java, outlook, exchangewebservices

I want to know is there any Outlook APIs for getting meeting room details that who have booked the particular room for the whole day. I need get such details through APIs like, 1.)Meeting room is booked or not for any particular time. 2.) If booked, who has
 booked that room. Employee Name, and other details if any.

I need to know what are the APIs need to be used, I need to develop in JAVA, so java api is required. Any sample is there, please provide me to work on. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [EWS Java API](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api) that is now open-source.  That would be the best way for your scenario if you targeting both customers using Office 365 or those who run Exchange on-premises.  If you are targeting Office 365 only, you can use our [Calendar REST APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations).  However, for REST APIs, you will need to wait for support for service accounts that will be released in the coming weeks.  You will need to use a service account to access the conference room's calendar and then will able to retrieve the info you are looking for.

**[UPDATE]:** Support for service accounts for REST APIs is now available. Please see our [blog announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/22/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx) for more details and let us know if you have any questions.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you are interested in the [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx).

Comment: Yes i am interested in it. But, i want some sample regarding my query to work in it. It would be better if i get any java sample.

Comment: It doesn't matter what programming language you are using. It is just a service with a SOAP notation. It looks like you are looking for a sample how to work with web services.

Comment: Yes, i want some web services to get meeting room details whether room is already booked or not.

Comment: You need to learn how to work with web services in Java first.

Comment: web services is fine.. related to ews api..i need some tutorial, or some samples

Comment: Did you hava a chance to look at MSDN articles?